# Cassandra setInputSplitSize is not working properly

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am using Hadoop + Cassandra. I use setInputSplitSize(1000) to not overload mappers (and receive out of heap memory) as default it is 64K. All together I have only 2M lines to process. Actually every split should be ~1000 rows.

The problem is that some mappers still receive 64K rows and I do not why. Usually there are 2-3 mappers that have in status 4000% 64000% instead of just having 100%. When I check the log, I found 40K-64K rows processed. It is not crashing or giving out of memory, but these 2-3 tasks begin in the middle of processing and continue for 2-3 hours after all other have been processes.

Is it a normal behaviour? What can I do to make split size solid?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Cassandra are you using?  If it's not 0.7.8 or 0.8.4 try upgrading first.

If you still see this behavior, please create a bug report on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA.

Comment: than you for the comment, We use 0.8.2, but I will upgrade to 0.8.4

Comment: Can't check because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060095/cassandra-upgrade-0-8-2-0-8-4-get-error-failed-connecting-to-all-endpoints