# Cassandra Upgrade 0.8.2->0.8.4 get error "failed connecting to all endpoints"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, thrift

After upgrade of cassandra from 0.8.2 to 0.8.4, got this error
I have restarted cassandra, removed data, etc. nothing helps
I have 6 identical machines in the cloud, before it was working fine.
If I make netstat then it shows port 9160 listening
nodetool ... ring  - responces with 6 machines UP.

what could be the problem? : (

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not get input splits
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
        at WordCount.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at WordCount.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: failed connecting to all endpoints slave1/98.188.69.242
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:153)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed connecting to all endpoints slave1/98.188.69.242
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSubSplits(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:234)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.access$200(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:70)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:190)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you have solved the problem. I met with the same problem as yours (Same configuration as yours too) and trrie to solve it.
Problem location:

> public List call() throws Exception { ... List
>   tokens = getSubSplits(keyspace, cfName, range, conf); ...

In the method getSubSplits when calling method

> createConnection(host, ConfigHelper.getRpcPort(conf), true)

, the format of host is not right. It is  hostname/10.197.34.111 sometimes (ip_address), so createConnection will fail. We need to extract the ip address and then call createConnection.

You can try to change the code and try Hadoop again.

Good luck!